# Feature dimension of RGB color histogram?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, histogram, rgb, feature-extraction

I am unsure about this but I want to compute features around interest points computed by surf using RGB color Histogram. I guess the final feature will be 256 dimensional long. However, I am unsure if this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension of the RGB color histogram is determined by how many bins you use for each channel. The dimension will be `24 (8+8+8)` if you use `8` bins for each of them.

Comment: oh thanks I just noticed them. I have one more question if you can help me out in. At the moment I am using SURF features and RGB color histogram for feature computation. For example for detection of a cup on the table. Do you think the use of histogram feature is good enough here? I mean when i compute the features of the cup model which is 40 x 40 pixel image and I perform detection on 640 x 480 image which will contain a lot more colours. Is it good idea to use RGB histogram descriptor as well here.

Comment: @user1965914 RGB color histogram is OK here because the dimension will be same no matter how large the image is as long as they use same bins.

Comment: Actually I am confused like the image of the model only contains the cup while the image for detection contains other cluster of colors. Wont the 2 histogram won't match. Sorry I am just confused.

Comment: @user1965914 They will not match in this case because the larger image contains other content. You can try search with relative similar sizes.

Comment: Like sliding windows like search would be good enough.. Also if I compute histogram of each interest points which u answered will be 24 dimensional vector for each interest point right. just confirming

Comment: @user1965914 It will be 24 but most of them will be 0. I don't recommend you to compute RGB histogram for each point. Histogram is a statistic value (i.e. for pixels not a single pixel).

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for which type of descriptor would be better together with SURF.

Comment: @user1965914 I am not quite familiar with SURF. Maybe you can ask another SO question to find it out. :)